# In Winui-3 Not Able to add Space between item in ComboBox and ListView

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, winui-3

I am facing an issue in WinUI 3 with ComboBox and ListView. Here's how to add space between two items (including the hover effect). If I add a margin, it only affects the content and not the hover effect. Is there a solution for this? Please refer to the image below to see the desired output I'm looking for.

[image: Reference Image]

Here I want to add Spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

It seems that you need to customize your item more. You need to change the default style of the `ListViewItem`. Find a property called `PointerOverBackground` and change its default value.

I made a sample to change the color as ligthpink.

Code:

```
    <StackPanel.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}" />
        
        <Style x:Key="DefaultListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}" />
            <!--#region Adding margin for listview items -->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
            <!--#endregion-->
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,0,12,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root"
                                               ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                               Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                               FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" 
                                               FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" 
                                               FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}"
                                               FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"
                                               FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}"
                                               SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" 
                                               CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                                               DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" 
                                               DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                                               FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" 
                                               FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" 
                                               PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" 
                                               PointerOverBackground="LightPink"
                                               PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                                               SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}" 
                                               SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}" 
                                               SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                                               PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}" 
                                               SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                                               DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                               DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                               ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                               ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                                               CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCornerRadius}" 
                                               CheckPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckPressedBrush}"
                                               CheckDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckDisabledBrush}" 
                                               CheckBoxPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPointerOverBrush}" 
                                               CheckBoxPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPressedBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" 
                                               CheckBoxSelectedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxSelectedPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedPointerOverBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxSelectedPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedPressedBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxSelectedDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedDisabledBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBorderBrush}" 
                                               CheckBoxPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPointerOverBorderBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxPressedBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPressedBorderBrush}"
                                               CheckBoxDisabledBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxDisabledBorderBrush}" 
                                               CheckBoxCornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxCornerRadius}" 
                                               SelectionIndicatorCornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorCornerRadius}"
                                               SelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled}" 
                                               SelectionIndicatorBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorBrush}"
                                               SelectionIndicatorPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorPointerOverBrush}"
                                               SelectionIndicatorPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorPressedBrush}"
                                               SelectionIndicatorDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorDisabledBrush}"
                                               SelectedDisabledBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedDisabled}" />

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem >123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

**Old:**

Please try to change the `margin` property of the **ListViewItem** in the **ItemContainerStyle**
Like this:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource RadioButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListViewItem >123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>123</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: When we hover on that item how to change that colour. in your case on second item (grey colour)

Comment: @Mahesh You need to change the default style of the LIstViewItem. I've updated my answer. Please check that.

Comment: Accepted your answer.! where I learn WinUI3 Deeply cause in documentation have very less information. @Roy

Comment: @Mahesh You could start with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/

Comment: I want to convert this code into WinUi3. Can you help me for this...!
```
```

Comment: @Mahesh The code could be directly used in WinUI3 applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-style the `ListViewItem`/`ComboBoxItem` like this:

**ListView**

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}"
            TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10,15,20" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

**ComboBox**

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxItemStyle}"
            TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10,15,20" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```